# Нужно ли при удалении проверять, была ли выделена память?

Tags: c++

Есть указатель на объект, и он указывает на выделенную память через new. Можно спокойно вызывать для него delete? А если он не указывает на созданный в динамической памяти объект, то delete ошибку выполнения не вызовет? Как проверить, что объект указывает на выделенный участок который можно удалить? Просто если if(object != null) или (object) и потом аж вызывать delete? Или delete и сам может определить, есть ли что-то для удаления или нет?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Если указатель указывает на объект, выделенный при помощи `new`, и для него ещё ни разу не был вызван `delete`, то вызывать `delete` можно. Также можно вызывать `delete` по нулевому указателю (сколько угодно раз).

В любом другом случае — нельзя.

Ответственность за соблюдение этого условия лежит на программисте, ни компилятор, ни runtime-библиотека за вас этого не проверят.

Хуже того, несоблюдение этого условия есть undefined behaviour: программа считается необратимо сломанной, и может вылететь, а может (что гораздо хуже) не вылететь, а работать как будто бы всё в порядке.

Обычно помогает простой принцип: если вы сами выделили объект, вам его и удалять. Если к вам он пришёл со стороны, как правило ответственность за удаление лежит на том, кто его создавал.

Но возможны и исключения, когда вместе с объектом вам передаётся и обязанность его удалить. Смотрите документацию функций, которые вы вызываете.

С другой стороны, в современном C++ работа с «сырыми» указателями происходит довольно редко. Обычно между частями программы передаётся «умный» указатель (например, `shared_ptr`), при этом проблема снимается, поскольку объект по указателю автоматически удаляется, когда нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Стандартный вариант использования new/delete включает в себя манипуляции с установкой указателя при его инициализации в nullptr и после вызова delete в nullptr. Таким образом, если указатель указывает в nullptr, это является сигналом, что он не указывает на участок памяти. В противном случае указывает. Но это, скорее, вопрос стиля.

Определить по указателю, указывает ли он на начало выделенной памяти через new или куда-то еще - невозможно (теоретически возможно, зная реализацию new и malloc, но это костыли и танцы с бубном, которые нельзя делать никогда).

Хорошим сегодня стилем является использование **vector< char >** в качестве переменной для хранения буффера. Стандарт C++ гарантирует, что будет выделен один блок памяти. При этом работа через vector освобождает программиста от заботы об освобождении памяти.
Кроме того, освобождает от проблем с exception как при выделении памяти, так и в случае, если exception будет выброшен позже, при сворачивании стэка выделенная под вектор память корректно освободится, что не произойдет, если она выделена через new.
Издержки производительности не должны волновать до этапа оптимизации, и должны быть очень незначительными.

Кроме того, важный момент про использование сторонних библиотек: поскольку варианты реализации alloc/free и new/delete могут разниться от компилятора к компилятору, удалять можно лишь то, что вы сами создали. Никакая память, выделенная в уже собранной библиотеке не должна освобождаться в ее клиенте и наоборот.
UPD: в большей степени это относится к ОС семейства Windows.

Comment: @smallFish, для полноты картины, может быть, стоило бы добавить, что содержимое вектора в итоге все-таки выделяется (по умолчанию, конечно) тем же самым вызовом `new`.

Comment: @smallFish: совет насчёт сторонних библиотек валиден только на Windows. На Linux-платформe, насколько я понимаю, runtime-библиотека [общая](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8868913/276994) для программы и всех используемых библиотек.

Comment: @VladD, насколько я понимаю - для Linux так же актуально. Если, к примеру, библиотека собрана компилятором, который затем обновлен, у него могут быть другие реализации alloc, stl и чего угодно. И клиент, собранный обновленной версией, который попытается освободить память, выделенную библиотекой, собранной старой версией компилятора, может дать undefined behaviour.

Comment: @smallFish: Я бы уточнил у @avp, он у нас специалист по Linux-платформе.

Насколько я понимаю, `malloc` вместе со всей рантайм-библиотекой не будет прикомпилирован в исполнимый файл, а будет подключён в рантайме, один на весь процесс.

Насчёт stl-классов я не настолько уверен, конечно.

Comment: @VladD звучит очень разумно про рантайм, я не знаю, как правильно. Подождем avp, истина дороже всего :)

Comment: @avp у vector есть возможность заменять allocator, что, теоретически, может позволить, например, сразу писать тело вектора на жесткий диск или в память видеокарты, в обход оперативки, и я не уверен, что дефолтная реализация обязательно (т.е. это прописано в стандарте) использует new, без возможности каких-то своих "выкрутасов".

Comment: Насколько  мне известно, в Linux (да и других \*nix) `malloc` находится в shared library (`libc.so`).

Если же кто-то использует свой вариант (статический), то наверное ему стоит предупреждать остальных пользователей библиотеки об этом :)

--

@smallFish, похоже Вы слишком серьезно подходите к написанию переносимых программ (на самом деле это в известной мере иллюзия, что-то вроде горизонта -- линии к которой можно идти бесконечно).

--

Небольшое добавление о библиотеках. Обычно в `manpage` пишут о том, как правильно освобождать возвращаемую из нее память (`free` или `"mylib_memrelease"`).